# A die is thrown $13$ times. What is the probability that exactly two numbers appear?

Tags: probability

A die is thrown $13$ times. What is the probability that exactly two numbers appear?

I did it this way: $P(A)=\frac{\binom{6}{2}(2^{13}-2)}{6^{13}}$. To pick two numbers that will appear $13$ times I have $\binom{6}{2}$ ways. $2^{13}-2$: any of those two numbers will appear $2^{13}$ times and I subtract $2$ if one of those numbers appears every time. Is this correct?

Comment: try to calculate all situations - appearing two different numbers

Comment: Yes, this looks good.  For things like this, I like to run sanity checks.  Replace $13$ by $n$ and check by hand for small $n$.  Easy to confirm the formula for $n=1,2,3$ for example.

Comment: yeap,your solution is correct !